# Google API login: Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://path-to-script/google-login-api/

Tags: google-api

I have a AWS EC2 and install Apache/PHP/MySQL. I would like to create a signup by Google API. I can access via ip address or http://testwhy.duckdns.org/login.php

It only displays:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://path-to-script/google-login-api/
```

It looks like something wrong with Credentials.

I setup:

Authorized JavaScript origins

```
http://educationfirst.duckdns.org
```

Not sure why it diplays it is not allowed.

Comment: What do you have set in Redirect uri not JavaScript origins? should be http://testwhy.duckdns.org/login.php